# react native app wont start on ios, ld: Undefined symbols:

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, npm, alamofire

my app stopped working on ios simulator after xcode 15.2 update, keeps getting this error:

```
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lc++'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'CoreAudioTypes': framework 'CoreAudioTypes' not found
ld: Undefined symbols:
  Swift.Duration.components.getter : (seconds: Swift.Int64, attoseconds: Swift.Int64), referenced from:
      Alamofire.WebSocketRequest.startAutomaticPing(every: Swift.Duration) -> () in libAlamofire.a[44](WebSocketRequest.o)
      Alamofire.WebSocketRequest.startAutomaticPing(every: Swift.Duration) -> () in libAlamofire.a[44](WebSocketRequest.o)
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

thanks for your help...

i tried these solutions and they wont help:

- xcode downgrade to 15.0
- clean npm, cocoapods, xcode caches
- delete and download project repo
- List item

**edit: the problem was related to the automatic update of the Alamofire pods version (5.8.1 -> 5.9.0). i undid it and the problem is solved.**